# What is a perl one liner to replace a substring in a string?

Tags: perl, csh

Suppose you've got this C shell script:

```
setenv MYVAR "-l os="\""redhat4.*"\"" -p -100"
setenv MYVAR `perl -pe "<perl>"`
```

Replace  with code that will either replace "-p -100" with "-p -200" in MYVAR or add it if it doesn't exist, using a one liner if possible.

Comment: I haven't figured out how to pass an environment variable into perl with it being interpreted by the shell. The shell trips on "*" upon evaluation.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: In this case, you do want it to be interpreted by the shell when you pass it to Perl.

Comment: You really should avoid `csh` for scripting. Escaping is limited, broken.

Comment: Most commands will use the latter option if it's provided twice. Have you tried just adding `-p -200` to `MYVAR` unconditionally?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm going to do I think. But it bugs me that I can't find a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

The topic does not correspond to content, but I think it may be usefull if someone posts an answer to topic-question. So here is the perl-oneliner:

```
echo "my_string" | perl -pe 's/my/your/g'
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want will look something like

```
perl -e'                                             \
   use Getopt::Long qw( :config posix_default );     \
   use String::ShellQuote;                           \
   GetOptions(\my %opts, "l=s", "p=s") or die;       \
   my @opts;                                         \
   push @opts, "-l", $opts{l} if defined($opts{l});  \
   push @opts, "-p", "-100";                         \
   print(shell_quote(@opts));                        \
' -- $MYVAR
```

- First, you need to parse the command line. That requires knowing the format of the arguments of the application for which they are destined.

  For example, `-n` is an option in the following:

  ```
  perl -n -e ...
  ```

  Yet `-n` isn't an option in the following:

  ```
  perl -e -n ...
  ```

  Above, I used Getopt::Long in POSIX mode. You may need to adjust the settings or use an entirely different parser.
- Second, you need to produce `csh` literals.

  I've had bad experiences trying to work around `csh`'s defective quoting, so I'll leave those details to you. Above, I used String::ShellQuote's `shell_quote` which produces `sh` (rather than `csh`) literals. You'll need to adjust.

---

Of course, once you got this far, you need to get the result back into the environment variable unmangled. I don't know if that's possible in `csh`. Again, I leave the `csh` quoting to you.

Comment: Wow, that's quite long! Thanks for the answer though. I was able to gleam some insight from it. I think the main problem with this is that $MYVAR is still interpreted by the shell before being passed to Perl.

Comment: As it should be. The code I posted relies on `-l os="redhat4.*" -p -100` having been split into `-l`, `os=redhat4.*`, `-p` and `-100` by the shell.